# Возможно ли вырезать из макета png картинку без потери качества?

Tags: html, css

Есть ли способ вырезать png из макета что бы при увеличении области страницы не было такой заметной потери качества? Дело обстоит с логотипом который должен иметь прозрачный фон, ну или придется склеить этот логотип с бекграундом если вариантов не будет. Примерные высота и ширина лого 50х50 px.

Comment: Если у вас изначально лого 50 на 50 пикселей, то при увеличении оно естественно будет терять качество и не важно jpg это gif или png. Любое растровое изображение будет терять качество при увеличении. Как вариант вы можете сохранить картинку в размере например 300х300 пикселей и при помощи ксс уменьшить размер до 50, тогда по идеи при увеличении картинка должна быть четче.

Comment: спасибо большое за идею, довольно интересное решение обязательно попробую)

Comment: Используйте SVG формат https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG

Comment: Далеко не все картинки следует использовать в векторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого варианта нет. Вам нужна векторная графика, то есть SVG.
Когда вставляют png, то делают картинки 2x и 3x, чтобы отображались нормально на ретинах.

В вашем случае логотип должен быть отрисован огромного размера и уменьшен средствами css до 50px. Тогда при увеличении потери качества происходить не будет.